# Run MySQL database with Docker Compose

Tags: server, permissions, mysql, docker, container

I am stuck in an issue related with Ubuntu, Docker, share folders of Virtual Box. Sorry about that I am not able to specify more, but I have no idea what should be the source of the problem.
It appears when I run the 'docker-compose up' command and try to run the official MySQL container.
But first let me explain the background.

I have a Wordpress project.
My plan was that to make code writing on my host OS (Windows 10 Home) and run the codes on my Guest OS (Ubuntu 18.04.2). With more detail I would work with Docker on my Guest OS and provide 3 containers and building/running them with Docker Compose.
Containers would be these:

- Wordpress
- MySQL
- PHPMyAdmin

You can find the full content of my Docker Compose file below.
*I have an issue with the container of database, that's why I commented out the others.*

```
version: '3'

services:
  
  # wordpress
  # wordpress:
  #   image: 'wordpress:latest'
  #   container_name: 'wordpress1-wordpress'
  #   networks:
  #     - wordpress1-wordpress-network
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./:/var/www/html
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     - database
  #   environment:
  #     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
  #     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
  #     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp123
  #   ports:
  #     - '8000:80'
  
  # database
  database:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    container_name: 'wordpress1-database'
    networks:
      - wordpress1-wordpress-network
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress1
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp123

  # phpmyadmin
  # phpmyadmin:
  #   image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest'
  #   container_name: 'wordpress1-phpmyadmin'
  #   networks:
  #     - wordpress1-wordpress-network
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     - database
  #   environment:
  #     PMA_HOST: database:3306
  #     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
  #   ports:
  #     - 8080:80

networks:
  wordpress1-wordpress-network: 
    driver: bridge
```

The Guest OS has been started in the background.
I work with Visual Studio Code on my Host OS.
I open a new terminal and make an SSH connection, so I can use the Docker from here.
At the very begining, my folder contains only the 'docker-compose.yaml' file and nothing else.
After the first 'docker-compose up' command a new empty folder is created and some error logs show in my terminal.

```
wordpress1-database | 2019-08-08T09:37:33.088721Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
```

[image: You can see a print screen with more detail under this link]

When I change the Guest OS folder path in the yaml file then everything works.
Example: change the './db_data' part into '/var/db_data' then I cannot see any errors.
That's why I think that it should be a permission error.

You can see below the current settings:

```
webdev@docker:/media/sf_development/_practice/wordpress1$ ll
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Aug  8 09:37 ./
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Jul 28 07:59 ../
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Aug  8 09:46 db_data/
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1285 Aug  8 09:37 docker-compose.yaml*
webdev@docker:/media/sf_development/_practice/wordpress1$
```

And you can see the current group settings:

```
webdev:x:1004:docker,vboxsf
vboxusers:x:113:
vboxsf:x:114:webdev,docker
docker:x:999:webdev
```

It would be important to keep the shared volumes in the same project folder, so how can I fix this issue?

Thanks any tips, advices in advance!

Comment: Do you *really* want the volume to be at /var/lib/mysql? Isn't it better to let docker handle it as a normal volume?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with `mysql:latest` and 5.8. Fixed with 5.7.

```
database:
    image: 'mysql:5.7' <--
```

See another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55253969/12555857).